# Replace single character in string with new line

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to edit some text files by replacing single characters with a new line.

Before:

```
Bill Fred Jack L Max Sam
```

After:

```
Bill Fred Jack
Max Sam
```

This is the closest I have gotten, but the single character is not always going to be 'L'.

```
 cat File.txt | tr "L" "\n
```

Comment: If it's now always L, how do you know what it is?

Comment: I was hoping based on character length of the word. Anything that is only 1 character.

Comment: Do it in `awk`. Loop through the fields on the line, call `length($i)` to get its length, and if that's `1` print a newline instead of the field.

Comment: `sed "s/\s\S\s/\n/g"` ??? this works ???

Comment: Your question says you want to replace the letter with newline. But in your example, you still have the letter in the output, so it wasn't replaced.

Comment: Crap.. forgot to change that. Sorry.

Comment: Jose Ricardo Bustos M.   - That woks, could you post it as an answer, so I can Accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
sed "s/\s\S\s/\n/g" File.txt
```

explanation,

You want to convert any word formed by a single character in special character: line break `\n`,

`\s` : Space and tab

`\S` : Non-whitespace characters

Answer (score 1):

```
bash-4.3$ cat file.txt                                                                                      
1.Bill Fred Jack L Max Sam                                                                                  
2.Bill Fred Jack M Max Sam                                                                                  
3.Bill Fred Jack N Max Sam                                                                                  
bash-4.3$ sed 's/\s[A-Z]\s/\n/g' file.txt                                                                   
1.Bill Fred Jack                                                                                            
Max Sam                                                                                                     
2.Bill Fred Jack                                                                                            
Max Sam                                                                                                     
3.Bill Fred Jack                                                                                            
Max Sam
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed "s/[[:blank:]][[:alpha:]][[:blank:]]/\
/g" YourFile
```

posix version

assuming that single letter is inside the string and not to the edge (start or end)